# Same Response Object with different xml names

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, marshalling

I have written two Rest based web methods in a service :

```
 Response doSomething() ;

 Response doSomething2()
```

Now , I want to marshal these responses as two different xml names . So that, the response looks like :

```
 **<doSomethingResponse>**   for doSomething()

 **<doSomething2Response>**   for doSomething2()
```

What is the best way to do this. I am using jaxB for marshalling.

Comment: You need to clarify in which part of the xml structure you want the responses to differ. Normally you should have 2 different String objects representing your 2 different Response objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage a `JAXBElement` to supply the root element name.  In the example below we will use a `JAXBElement` to make the root node of the response `FOO`.

```
   @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response get() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName("Jane");
        customer.setLastName("Doe");
        JAXBElement<Customer> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(new QName("FOO"), Customer.class, customer);
        return Response.ok(jaxbElement).build();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, on a similar note I also want to do the exact opposite. Requests come with different xml names (same structure, only root element names differ)  should map to the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `@WebResult` or `@XmlElement` annotations:

```
@WebResult(name="doSomethingResponse")
//or
//@XmlElement(name="doSomethingResponse")
Response doSomething();

@WebResult(name="doSomething2Response")
//or
//@XmlElement(name="doSomething2Response")
Response doSomething2();
```

Comment: WebResult is for jaxws.
XmlElement is not working. It takes the name in xmlRootElement.
Am I missing smoething here?